# Javascript, Responsive design, Multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a webpage which has 3 canvas. The canvas should change its size according to the screen.
My method works for only one canvas(the one I specify the ID). I'm using the getElementByID which takes only one. Each canvas has their own ID but the same class name. So I did getElementByClassName but its not working on other screen. The size remain the default size(the size in the canvas tag)
Then I tried querySelectorAll for all IDs(cause it was working for 1 id) but still not working.
Please, some help here.
Thanks.

```
function setCanvas() {
    // using % of viewport for canvas bitmap (pixel ratio not considered)
    var canvas = document.querySelectorAll("#BgCanvas, #SnakeCanvas, #Angel_PowerBallCanvas")
        , vwWidth = window.innerWidth
        , vwHeight = window.innerHeight
        , percent = 60;
    canvas.width = Math.round(vwWidth * percent / 100); // integer pixels
    canvas.height = Math.round(vwHeight * percent / 100);
    // not to be confused with the style property which affects CSS, ie:
    // canvas.style.width = "60%"; // CSS only, does not affect bitmap
}
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a *collection* (an array), you have to use a loop!

Answer (score 0):

Try this example using `getElementByClassName` but you need to convert it into an array because `getElementByClassName` is an HTML Collection.

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas1" class="canvas" ></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" class="canvas" ></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" class="canvas" ></canvas>
```

CSS

```
.canvas {width: 100px; height: 100px;border: 1px solid red; margin: 10px; float: left;}
```

SCRIPT

```
function setCanvas() {
    // using % of viewport for canvas bitmap (pixel ratio not considered)
   var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas")
        , vwWidth = window.innerWidth
        , vwHeight = window.innerHeight
        , percent = 60;
        var w = Math.round(vwWidth * percent / 100);
        var h = Math.round(vwHeight * percent / 100);

        // getElementByClassName("canvas")  is a collection of HTML objects
        // you'll need to convert the getElementByClassName into array by using [].slice.call()
         [].slice.call(canvas).forEach(function(element) {
            element.setAttribute("style", "height:" + h + "px;" + " width:" + w + "px;");
        });
}
setCanvas();
```